# immediately invoke string-rectangle upon rectangle-mark-mode selection

Tags: rectangle

A common use-case that I have is to add a string to the same position of each line of text.

For example, I might start with

```
expect(one).toEqual(true);
expect(two).toEqual(false);
```

which I want to transform into

```
expect(oneValue).toEqual(true);
expect(twoValue).toEqual(false);
```

What I currently do is:

- place my cursor after `one`
- press `C-x <SPC>` (invoking `rectangle-mark-mode`)
- press `C-n` to extend the zero-width rectangle down one row
- (look up the keystrokes and then) press `C-x r t Value <RET>` to invoke `string-rectangle`, thereby adding the string `Value` to the desired locations

I would like to simply start typing after selecting a rectangle with `rectangle-mark-mode`, and the rectangular selection would be interactively replaced with what I'm typing (including the case where I've marked a zero-width rectangle). In other words, I want to eliminate the `C-x r t` step above and just start typing `Value` immediately. How can I accomplish this?

I'm also curious why this isn't the default behavior of Emacs, since I can't think of a disadvantage to this approach.

Comment: There is no magic. Keys are all equals in Emacs. `C-x r t` runs a command, `V`, `a`, `l`, `u` and `e` all run a command as well. You have to teach Emacs what's the mean of "start typing".

Comment: Also [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) offers a convenient way to do this, once you get used to the key-bindings.

Comment: `string-rectangle` long pre-dates `rectangle-mark-mode` -- you can save yourself a keystroke by using `C-SPC` rather than `C-x SPC`.

Comment: I recently wrote some code for this [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8s617r/avoid_having_to_invoke_stringrectangle_to_insert/).

Comment: @Omar, would you please copy your solution into an Answer here?

Comment: Done, @phils! Although I chose to highlight Stefan Monnier's superior solution instead.

Answer (score 4):

This came up [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8s617r/avoid_having_to_invoke_stringrectangle_to_insert/) where I wrote two ways of achieving this, but I think the nicest solution was offered by Stefan Monnier:

```
(defun string-rectangle-with-initial (char)
  (interactive (list last-input-event))
  (push char unread-command-events)
  (call-interactively 'string-rectangle))

(define-key rectangle-mark-mode-map
  [remap self-insert-command] 'string-rectangle-with-initial)
```

On Emacs 25 and later, `string-rectangle` has a lovely dynamic preview of the result. If you want similar interactivity on older Emacsen, you can try one of my solutions:

```
(defun string-rectangle-single-char ()
  (interactive)
  (when (< (point) (mark)) (exchange-point-and-mark))
  (string-rectangle (region-beginning)
                    (region-end)
                    (this-command-keys))
  (exchange-point-and-mark)
  (forward-char)
  (exchange-point-and-mark)
  (setq deactivate-mark nil))

(define-key rectangle-mark-mode-map
  [remap self-insert-command] 'string-rectangle-single-char)
```

Answer (score 3):

Offhand I'm inclined to agree with the feature request -- with `rectangle-mark-mode` enabled, `self-insert-command` seems (AFAICS) to exit the rectangle mode and insert at point, just as if the rectangle wasn't selected; so your idea seems like a good idea for a new option. `M-x report-emacs-bug` and suggest it?

There *is* a shorter key sequence than the one you're using in `rectangle-mark-mode-map` however.  If you mark the rectangle with `C-x SPC` then:

- `C-t` runs `string-rectangle`.
- `C-o` runs `open-rectangle`.

---

FYI I use `string-rectangle` that way when I want to *replace* existing text; but if I'm purely inserting then I tend to make use of the rectangle support in `cua-selection-mode` which can operate rather like what you're asking for:

- `C-RET` to mark the top of the column
- Move point down to the bottom position
- Start typing
- `C-RET` to exit

That's just one use-case for it.  `M-x find-library RET cua-base RET` and read about "CUA rectangle support" for the full details.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been using [Stefan Monnier’s function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39414/immediately-invoke-string-rectangle-upon-rectangle-mark-mode-selection/42597#42597) for some time and along the way I’ve fixed some of its shortcomings, namely, that it doesn’t trigger on yanking or when using `quoted-insert`, and that it duplicates the first character when executed as part of a keyboard macro.

Making it work with `yank` and `quoted-insert` is just a matter of remapping those two commands in addition to `self-insert-command`, and the last issue is solved by avoiding to push `char` to `unread-command-events` while executing a keyboard macro.

```lisp
(defun string-rectangle-with-initial (char)
  "Call ‘string-rectangle’ before processing CHAR."
  (interactive (list last-input-event))
  (barf-if-buffer-read-only) ; Emulate ‘(interactive "*")’.
  (unless executing-kbd-macro
    (push char unread-command-events))
  (call-interactively #'string-rectangle))

(with-eval-after-load 'rect
  (define-key rectangle-mark-mode-map [remap self-insert-command] #'string-rectangle-with-initial)
  (define-key rectangle-mark-mode-map [remap yank] #'string-rectangle-with-initial)
  (define-key rectangle-mark-mode-map [remap quoted-insert] #'string-rectangle-with-initial))
```

Answer (score -1):

(This answer doesn't tell you how to do what you request.  It tries to tell you why that behavior is not the default behavior.)

There are lots of things you might want to do with a rectangular region, just like there are lots of things you might want to do with a regular region.  Why suppose that whatever you type should be considered only as text to be used as `string-rectangle`?  That would seriously limit what you can do with a rectangular region.

The problem, I think, is that you are in the habit of creating a rectangular region, and not in the habit of just putting point and mark at the corners of what you want to consider as a rectangle.

(That said, maybe you could get the behavior you request, if you really want it, by fiddling with the `delete-selection` code.)

Comment: Good point about the analogy to regular regions. But to follow that analogy, my assumption was that anything special you'd want to do to with region would involve a modifier key such as `C`- or `M-`, and anything else would be considered an attempt to overwrite the region with text input.

Comment: Thank you for the point and mark suggestion, that is an good approach. 1) Set point and mark at the corners of a rectangle 2) invoke `C-x r t` and begin typing